# Why do the JPA2 MetaModel get generated with volatile members?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, metamodel

I have just used `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6` to generate the MetaModel for my JPA2 entities.

```
@javax.annotation.Generated
(value="org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6",
   date="Tue Nov 22 09:49:03 CET 2011")
public class Entity_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entity,Entity> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entity,String> value;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Entity,String> order;
}
```

Can someone please explain why the attributes are marked volatile in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thread that sets the static variables might not be the same as the thread that you use to access them, so the `volatile` modifier is required to synchronize memory between all threads.

The scenario without `volatile` is like this:

1. Your thread accesses the variables before the JPA provider is initialized and gets `null` for the static fields
2. The JPA provider is initialized from a different thread and sets the static fields to non-null values
3. Your thread accesses the static fields again. In this case the cached memory of your thread will not see the changes and continue to return `null` for all static fields.

Comment: Thanks Ingo - think I am going mad, of course they need to be initialized!  As per the spec "When the entity manager factory for a persistence unit is created, it is the responsibility of the persistence provider to initialize the state of the metamodel classes of the persistence unit."  I saw the Sonar warnings and didn't think through... Accepted Answer

Comment: So ? Should we ignore like 'false positive' Sonar warnings instead of fix it ? @planetjones

Answer (score 3):

Despite the [meaning of `volatile` keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java) and Ingo's answer, it's worth noticing that every JPA generator is **required to** generate volatile metadata fields (JPA 2.0 FR, *6.2.1.1 Canonical Metamodel*).

On page 199 you can read:

> For every persistent non-collection-valued attribute y declared by
>   class X, where the type of y is Y, the metamodel class must contain a
>   declaration as follows:
>
> `public static volatile SingularAttribute<X, Y>`
>   y;