# How to fix the Hibernate metamodel class' issues Make this "public static id" field final which is raised by Sonar

Tags: java, hibernate, sonarqube

I create the Hibernate metamodel classes as the article.
http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/static-metamodel/

Sonar give me this critical issue that I want to fix:
[image: Issue screenshot]

Sonar suggestion is

> **Noncompliant Code Example**
>
> public class Greeter {   public static Foo foo = new Foo();   ... }
>
> **Compliant Solution**
>
> public class Greeter {   public static final Foo FOO = new Foo();
>   ... }

But `SingularAttribute` is interface.

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd ignore that SonarQube Warning, as there's good reason why the field is defined as volatile (see Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564482/why-do-the-jpa2-metamodel-get-generated-with-volatile-members)). Also the JPA Spec defines the need for the 'volatile' Keyword.

Also, since these classes are generated you can't really change them anyways.

You could add a `@SuppressWarning("squid:S2386")` to the classes, but again that won't work because the classes are generated (repeatably in your build as i assume).

So you could either mark all those Issues as false positive in Sonar or ignore those (generated) classes altogether by setting `sonar.exclusions` to something like `"*_.java"`